# Catching all exceptions without pylint error

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, try-except

```
import traceback

def func():
    try:
        -- do something --
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

For this code
***pylint*** reporting error: bare-except   *No exception type(s) specified , W0702,    Occurs when an except clause doesn't specify exceptions type to catch.*

Now, if I want all exceptions to be captured without pylint error. Is there a way.
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can locally disable pylint if you are sure of what you are doing (as you seem to be here)

With the following comment

```
# pylint: disable=W0702
```

If my memory serves me right, you should use it this way

```
import traceback

def func():
    try:
        -- do something --
    except: # pylint: disable=W0702
        traceback.print_exc()
```

As Jack mentionned below, it is probably better to be more explicit about the warning:

```
except: # pylint: disable=bare-except
```

Answer (score 16):

I prefer using this more *meaningful* style:

```py
def func():
    try:
        -- do something --
    except: # pylint: disable=bare-except
        traceback.print_exc()
```